# CSS under float right

Tags: css, css-float

I hope I will explain this well.
I have a div that has a style="float: right;" and in this div I have a table with some editor fields.
But now I would like to have two text editor boxes (in .NET MVC3 @Html.TextAreaFor) that would sit under these edit fields. 
But what happens is that the text editor boxes appear somewhere in the middle of the page and not under the right floated editor fields.
How do I make the text editors appear under the right floated editor fields?

Thank you

Comment: perhaps it would be better to put the editor field and box in i sub div each

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this by putting the right aligned div in the right cell of a two cell, one row table that I gave 100% width.
That forces the next view with text editor fields fit under this table because it is 100% in width.
It is not very elegant but it does the trick for now.

Thank you

Comment: Read about the clearfix trick here http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/

Comment: Interesting article. Thank you. Never heard about this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to apply `overflow:hidden` to the parent of the `div` with float right, assuming that the blocks that have to be below it are not in the same parent. But it sure would help to see your markup.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried this but doesn't seem to help. I would post the markup but I use a lot of partial MVC views and the whole page is constructed by 5 of those. And each view is bellow the other and the problem starts to appear with the last one that needs to fit under the right floated one. Is there some trick to insert some invisible elements that would force the last view to fit under the right floated one?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the div that holds the float is collapsing and you need to make it enclose the float. Sou you should use a common clearfix trick.